# mediation in R - interpretating the absolute value of total effect, ACME, and ADE (binary exposure, mediator, and outcome)

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation, causality, mediation

I am a beginner of mediation analysis. In my research, exposure, mediator, and outcome are binary (0: no, 1: yes). The data is clustered by unit. I have fitted the mediate model (M ~ E) and outcome model (O ~ E+M), and use the ‘mediate’ command for mediation analysis. However, I find myself struggling to interpret the results.
[image]

1. What is the meaning of the absolute values for ‘Total Effect’, ‘ACME (average)’, and ‘ADE (average)’? The exponential of these values are unlikely the ORs of total effect, indirect effect, and direct effect.
2. Is it possible to estimate the ORs(95%CIs) of total effect, indirect effect, and direct effect based on the output of mediate?

Comment: Does [this resource](https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/introduction-to-mediation-analysis) help?

Comment: Not 100%, but I don't think the mediate function from the psych package is appropriate for regression models with random intercepts. It might also have problems with glms. There are other options, like lavaan or mlma, that might work